# How to properly merge a user given generictype type to Class itself ? (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to merge user given generic type to class itself in constructor. But it's throwing `Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)` while I access merged property from instantiated class. Currently I am using `&`, but I want to merge it in the class.

**MyClass**

```js
class MyClass<ArgSourceT> {
  /**
   *  Instantiate class and load up the given object
   * @param source ArgSourceT
   */
  constructor(source: ArgSourceT) {
    Object.assign(this, source);
    // I want to do something like 
    // this as this & ArgSourceT
  }
}
```

**Current usage(solution)**

```js
const person = {
  name: {
    first: 'John',
    last: 'Doe',
  },
};
type PersonT = typeof person;
// I have to also merge with '&',
// so that it won't throw 
// Property 'address' does not exist on type 'Observer<PersonT>'.ts(2339)' 
// or
// Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
// when I access name from myClass.
const myClass = new MyClass(person) as MyClass<PersonT> & PersonT;
console.log('firstname', myClass.name);
```

Comment: what is `IMyClass` ?

Comment: MyClass's interface. Since it's not necessary for the scenario, I left it out.

Comment: If it is not necessary to reproduce the problem, you should remove it from the question.

Comment: OK, I've removed it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a little workaround. You can 'override' your class type signature by return this and defining the return type properly.
You can also define a merge function(see example)
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=8&ts=4.7.4&ssl=21&ssc=13&pln=16&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8BBATgcwMoHsBXTYAUwBUA+aAbwChpHoB6AKlYaelcYEkA7CABcw-IQEswQ0tFCQYogCbQQ+MMsIAHaEIAWM7OIBupftHwAjAFalgQzkx4ABTWExgAttAhESMrHi+ZOQOjKzMocD4gkKYhHb4mAAUmpjGUjI+xGQAXNABBNkUAJS00AC+dKHi-OJCScV5CMjyGDiFflTQAGT57UEUtKFcmKRCxGYA8ta2QgB08uLY-El64hAANDq663NZfsWhlZV0UTGy0AC80En8pADucEgoEKg00GB5wmn82BWUSXen2gACIAGb4fAgirFYpzGp1BqnBYsZjQIxgEDiRRVMGEfh2cTRaAeUg4UgYLYAIQBwPQWwseSpjXyPWgVKGIzGE2g0xsdgWUCWKzADMOJzOwmgymupPJtweTxaaBo5QBquKWyBeXBkOh5UOihRzDRGKxOKAA)

```
class MyClass<ArgSourceT> {
    /**
     *  Instantiate class and load up the given object
     * @param source ArgSourceT
     */
    constructor(private source: ArgSourceT) { }

    init(): MyClass<ArgSourceT> & ArgSourceT {
        return Object.assign(this, this.source)
    }
}

const c = (new MyClass<{ a: string }>({ a: "foo" })).init()
c.a // valid

function merge<A, B>(a: A, b: B): A & B {
    return Object.assign(a, b)
}

const d = merge(new MyClass<{}>({}), { a: "foo" })
d.a // valid
```

Comment: Thank you! But it is introducing `source` to `this` already even before `Object.assing`. If I want that I could use a private property in the class.